# How to Fix a Regex that Removes HTML Comments from Removing Conditional Comments?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code:

```
source = Regex.Replace(source, "<!--.*?-->", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

...and it works fine, except that it also strips away conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE]>???<![endif]-->
```

Can someone tell me how to update the regex so it doesn't remove conditional comments?

Comment: If it follows the traditional rules of regular expressions you want something like:

    Regex.Replace(source, "<!--\s?[^\\[].*?-->", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

eg. 'ignore any spaces, don't match if there's a [ mark after the comment start'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [negative lookaheads and negative look behinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
<!--(?!\[).*?(?!<\])-->
```

Should only match `<!--` not followed by [ and any `-->` not preceded by ], and of course, the .*? matches the text inbetween.

Tested using [Derek Slager's](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) very useful and quick RegEx tester:

Source Text:

```
<!--[if IE]>???<![endif]--> 
<!--Comment-->
```

Pattern:

```
<!--(?!\[).*?(?!<\])-->
```

Result:

Found 1 match:

```
1. <!--Comment-->
```